# 19th century-like transportation without horses?

Tags: transportation, extinction, industrial-age, mounts, livestock

So, let’s say, hypothetically ***A NUCLEAR WAR KICKS OFF DUE TO PROLONGED INTERNATIONAL TENSION, AND TURNS THE EARTH INTO A BLEAK, HOSTILE WASTELAND***. Now, let’s flash forward 197 years, to 2259. By now, humanity has reestablished its presence, and has rebuilt itself up to a mid-19 century-esque style of living. You see, back when that little radioactive party kicked off, a lot of animals didn’t make it. Namely, all Equidae are now extinct.

Now, my question is, how would transportation of goods and people in a 19 century-sequel setting be handled without the utility of horses.

Comment: You know trains already existed im the 19th century, right?

Comment: So, like, bicycles?

Comment: Have you ever read "The Rithmatist"? This 19th century-esque world has "springrails" (trains powered by springworks/gears) and horses made completely out of mechanical gears and parts.

Comment: @Renan is 97% right, trains were invented in 1804 so unless if you are talking about 1800-1803 it won't really work out. Perhaps the solution is just to ask about late 18th century instead of the 19th century.

Comment: Oxen were used many places horses were.  They're not good mounts but they do pull stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP appears not to have done any basic research into alternatives other than horses - there's are loads (elephants, camels, cattle, dogs, not to mention human powered devices like bikes).

Comment: @StephenG, that's not a valid reason for a close vote, that's the specific valid reason for a downvote. A close vote is not a super down vote.

Comment: @Separatrix Some time ago when the community voted to allow a wider range of questions, one of the issues raised was that posters would be expected to do basic research of their own, which is quite reasonable to expect.  This is a perfectly reasonable basis to VTC, IMO (and done on other SEs).

Comment: @StephenG, if you hover over the downvote button, it specifically says "This question does not show any research effort", that's what it's for. The question itself is no less valid for that.

Comment: @Separatrix The hover text is generic to *all* SEs and does not reflect the discussion I mentioned above is almost certainly more recent.  Earth SE has it's own community policies and histories that are not reflected by those generic features.

Comment: @StephenG, our discussion, over and over in our meta, is not to use close votes as super down votes, which is exactly what you're advocating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93470/discussion-between-stepheng-and-separatrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for post-apocalyptic barn yard animals

- Elephants
- Camels
- Bison
- Cows
- mutated dogs/mastiff

Or if you are looking for another answer for a society that may be shunning modern tech (as it got them killed once already) perhaps you could focus on people power.  Along the lines of a bicycle, but what if there was a pedal power car that needed 6 people to pedal in order to move cargo?

Answer (score 1):

Domesticated riding animals besides equids: oxen, zebu, two types of camel, yaks, water buffalo.

oxen in particular a great for hauling loads, and quite frankly thanks to humans cows are one of the most common species on the planet now, so there is plenty of source stock.

Other partially domesticated animals that might be used for riding, reindeer, ostrich, muskox